# I want to get id once delete button got clicked, I am unable to send its value in other page, php

Tags: php, mysql

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['first_name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['second_name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['contact_no'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['address'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['date_created'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td> <a href='delete.php' id=".$row['id']."'>Delete</a></td>";
        echo "</tr>";

    }
}
```

Comment: echo "<td> <a href='delete.php?id=".$row['id']."' id=".$row['id']."'>Delete</a></td>"; is not working?

Comment: You can send your id via in this mode:  `<a href='delete.php?id=".$row['id']."' id=".$row['id']."'>Delete</a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send value to delete.php like below

```
echo "<td> <a href='delete.php?id=".$row['id']."' id=".$row['id']."'>Delete</a></td>";
```

And get value of id on delete.php with like below

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try this

echo "<td> <a href='delete.php' id='".$row['id']."'>Delete</a></td>";
```

Comment: How does this solve the question? Can you highlight the difference and explain it?

Answer (score 0):

You simply assign that id value to one PHP variable and you can call that anywhere you want.

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
         $id=$row['id'];
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['first_name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['second_name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['contact_no'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['address'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['date_created'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td> <a href='delete.php' id='$id'>Delete</a></td>";
        echo "</tr>";

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use get variable at the end of url and then use it another page as $_GET['variable']
for more information http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

so change your code like this

```
<?php
if (mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) 
    { 
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['first_name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['second_name']; ?> </td>
            <td><?php echo $row['contact_no']; ?> </td>
            <td><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['address']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['date_created']; ?></td>
            <td><a href="delete.php?id='<?php echo $row['id']; ?>'">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
    <?php }
} ?>
```

on next page get the id of that button as `$id = $_GET['id'];`

Comment: how to retrieve two values?

Comment: change to this one by adding one more variable as &var=9  as <td><a href="delete.php?id='<?php echo $row['id']; ?>'&var=9">Delete</a></td>. and on another page access it as $_GET['var']